# Changing Desktops in /usr/share/xsessions has no effect

Tags: gnome

I installed dwm but cannot get it to display on the Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) login screen.
I added the desktop file to `/usr/share/xsessions`.
I also deleted the i3 with debug option from this directory but it still appears.
Reboot does not help.

The login page seems to ignore `/usr/share/xsessions` - is there something else I need to do?

### /usr/share/xsessions/dwm.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=DWM
Comment=DWM
Exec=dwm
Icon=dwm
Type=XSession
```

Answer (score 0):

This `dwm` package already ships the desktop file - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/dwm/filelist . So simple package (re)installation will be enough:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dwm
```

Its absence in GDM may indicate some bug in GDM. You can install and use LightDM instead:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

then reboot and select Dwm session on login screen:

> [image: Dwm on LightDM]